# Add Output of two Powershell commands into an Array

Tags: powershell, outlook

I've been trying to figure out if this is even possible in Powershell.  I'm trying to pull a list of all users and their email addresses into an array from the Outlook Global Address List so the resulting output would look like this:

```
Alice Peters petersa@wedsite.tld
Bob Jackson jackson@website.tld
etc
```

I'm currently able to pull the information using:

```
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application] $galSearch = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

$search = @($galSearch.Session.GetGlobalAddressList().AddressEntries | ForEach-Object {$_.GetExchangeUser().Name; $_.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress})

$search
```

As you might expect the result is formatted like this:

```
Alice Peters
petersa@wedsite.tld
Bob Jackson
jackson@website.tld
etc
```

Is there a way to have them be in pairs and not one above the other?

Comment: `$galSearch.Session.GetGlobalAddressList().AddressEntries | ForEach-Object GetExchangeUser |Select Name,PrimarySmtpAddress`

Comment: This worked well, though it took well over an hour to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Outlook doesn't have any content in the GAL so I can't verify my suggestion.

If the object types supports string handling, just joint the two results into one string.

```
ForEach-Object {
    $_.GetExchangeUser().Name + ' ' +  
    $_.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
}
```

Otherwise, try converting to strings first.

```
ForEach-Object {
    ($_.GetExchangeUser().Name).ToString() + ' ' +  
    ($_.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress).ToString()
}
```

Or you could go for creating hashtables instead.

Or, the simplest solution as Mathias pointed out in his comment, go for just selecting the properties.
That will return an object instead of arrays.